# How to get all json values in an ajax success?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have an example json result:

```
{"Products": [{"ProductIndex": "1", "ProductCode": "116001", "ProductPrice": "$517.00"},{"ProductIndex": "2", "ProductCode": "37732", "ProductPrice": "$288.00"}],"Totals": [{"CartTotal": "$805.00", "Quantity": "2", "DiscountTotal": "0", "LastProduct": "0"}]}
```

I have this jQuery:

```
     jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
           url: '/AjaxCart.asp',
           cache: false,
           dataType: 'text',
           success: function(data) {
              var json = eval('(' + data + ')');
              var quantity;
              var cartTotal;
              var screenId;
              quantity = json.Totals[0].Quantity;
              cartTotal = json.Totals[0].CartTotal;
              screenId = json.Products[0].ProductCode;
              $("#content_area").prepend(screenId);
              },
           error: function() {
              return false;
           }
        });
     });
```

It works, but screenid is only pulling the first value of ProductCode. I need it to loop through the entire result and display both ProductCode values. I've tried putting the .each function around different things but with no results. Any help?

I think I am close with this but it's still not working:

```
pIndex = json.Products[0];
for(var i = pIndex.length; i--;) {
screenItem = pIndex[i];
$("#content_area.").prepend(screenItem.ProductCode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to change `pIndex = json.Products[0];` to `pIndex = json.Products;`, at the moment you're trying to loop through a single object, the first element of the `Products` array.

```
pIndex = json.Products;
for(var i = 0; i < pIndex.length; i++) {
  screenItem = pIndex[i];

  var $span = $('<span />').text(screenItem.ProductCode);
  $("#content_area.").append($span);
}
```

Comment: Actually, can you help a little more? The result is this:
11600137732
How can I enable the ability to style each result with CSS at this point?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the code above so each item is wrapped in a `<span>` tag, obviously you can change this to use whichever tag you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always returning json from your ajax call, it would be best to set your ajax  dataType property to "json" so that you don't need to parse the text by yourself (with either the eval method or the parseJSON method). Also, the jQuery.each function is preferable to a standard javascript for loop.

I would write your code like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: '/AjaxCart.asp',
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
          jQuery.each(data.Products, function(index, element) {
             $("#content_area").prepend(element.ProductCode);
          });
       },
       error: function() {
          return false;
       }
    });
 });
```